# How to serialize multiple members of "this"

Tags: c#, serialization, this

I have a class with a couple of members I want to serialise to store state.

However, I want to serialise from WITHIN the class itself, not via some external class feeding it to a formatter.

So in theory I want to do something like:

```
[DataContract]
class MyClass
{
    [DataMember]
    private MyCompoundClass _someCompoundField;

    [DataMember]
    private int _someOtherField;

    private void SaveState()
    { 
         using (Stream stream = GetStream())
         {
             DataContractSerializer serialiser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
             serialiser.WriteObject(stream, this);
         }
    }

    private void LoadState()
    { 
         using (Stream stream = GetStream())
         {
             DataContractSerializer serialiser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
             this = (MyClass)serialiser.ReadObject(stream);
         }
    }
}
```

Now obviously the line

```
 this = (MyClass)serialiser.ReadObject(stream);
```

is nonsense, but you can see what I'm trying to do. I want to serialise the two fields of my class from within the class. (I am using the WCF serializer, but I assume this will be the same if I use XmlSerializer).

I tried to implement this properly by serialising each field myself like so:

```
private void SaveState()
{ 
    using (Stream stream = GetStream())
    {
        //serialise field 1
        DataContractSerializer serialiser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyCompoundClass));
        serialiser.WriteObject(stream, _someCompoundField);

        //serialise field 2
        serialiser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(int));
        serialiser.WriteObject(stream, _someOtherField);
    }
}
```

Now this works as a save, but when I come to read the document back in it throws an exception since there are two root nodes in the XML file.

How do I create my "wrapper" node to wrap my fields. Or is there some other way I should be doing this?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen any built-in deserialisation methods which modify an existing object, rather than returning a new one. Your options as I see them are:

1. Deserialise a new `MyClass` and copy the members over
2. Make `LoadState` static and have it return the deserialised `MyClass`
3. Use a different serialisation mechanism which can do what you want

Comment: 2) is out since many other object have references to the instance so it shouldn't change. 1) Seems messy and longwinded (but no more than my manual serialise I guess) 3) Would be my choice, but I'm not familiar enough with .Net yet to know what other options there are.

Comment: If the benefits will justify the effort, the messiness of 1) could probably be hidden behind a reflection-based API.

Comment: Yup, went with 1 in the end. Still feels wrong but by far the quickest method. :)

Answer (score 1):

you could at your LoadState do:

```
    private void LoadState()
    { 
         using (Stream stream = GetStream())
         {
             DataContractSerializer serialiser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
             MyClass deserialized = (MyClass)serialiser.ReadObject(stream);

             this._someCompoundField = deserialized._someCompoundField;
             this._someOtherField = deserialized._someOtherField;
         }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I've considered doing this, it seems messy though. :-/

Comment: @GazTheDestroyer: it will do the trick ;) however if you want to organize it a little bit you can add method at the MyClass like `private void FromMyClass(MyClass myClass) { /*here copy the values from the desirialized object to the current instance*/ }`

Answer (score 0):

Are you tied to a specific serializer? protobuf-net supports that use-case, for example:

```
[DataContract]
class MyClass
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    private MyCompoundClass _someCompoundField;

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    private int _someOtherField;

    private void SaveState()
    {
        using (Stream stream = GetStream())
        {
            ProtoBuf.Serializer.Serialize(stream, this);
        }
    }

    private void LoadState()
    {
        using (Stream stream = GetStream())
        {
            ProtoBuf.Serializer.Merge(stream, this);
        }
    }
}
```

Note the addition of `Order = n` on the member-attributes; that is because protobuf uses numeric identifiers on fields/properties, and needs a way to choose them. You can also use the project-specific `[ProtoContract]`/`[ProtoMember(n)]` attributes, but it works with the WCF ones too (as shown).

(`Merge` is also available on the non-generic 2.0 API - but you pass `this` in as an argument to `Deseroalize` instead)

Answer (score 0):

Put your deserialization method in a static method:

```
class MyClass
{
    public static MyClass LoadState()
    { 
         // Deserialize, and return the new MyClass instance.
    }
}
```

To serialize just some objects, annotate some fields to avoid serialization, or create a superclass or interface with just the fields in it you want to serialize.

Comment: Unfortunately the object instance must remain the same since other code is holding references to it.